# What is equivalent of Firebird SQL 'for do' and 'select into' for postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In a Firebird SQL stored procedure I use a 'select into' in a 'for do' loop and I don't find the equivalent for pg function.

```
         for  select purchase.quantity, purchase.purchasevalue, purchase.purchased, purchase.id from purchase
                            join cellarbook cb on purchase.fk_cellarbook_id = cb.id
                            join bottle bot on cb.fk_bottle_id = bot.id
                            where bot.id = :bottleid
                            order by purchase.purchased ASC
                            into :purquantity, :purvalue, :purdate, :purid
                do
                begin
                    /* calculate quantity on hand at point of purchase
                       here come some more 'select' and calculations and
                       then and 'update' */
                     select sum(psum.quantity) as purquantitysum from purchase
                         join cellarbook cb on psum.fk_cellarbook_id = cb.id
                         join bottle bot on cb.fk_bottle_id = bot.id
                         where bot.id = bottleid and psum.purchased <=  pur.purchased and psum.id <> pur.id
into :purquantitysum
                end
```

I think it is a 'for in loop' but I am hung up on what the equivalent for the 'select into' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a record variable for this:

```
declare
  r record;
begin
   for r in  
     select col_1, col_2 from some_table;
   loop
      select sum(x)
      from other_table
      where id = r.col_1;
   end loop;
end;
```

More examples are in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

---

When you run `update` or `select` statements inside a loop is usually code-smell ("row-by-row processing"). In most of the cases it is much more efficient to do a bulk processing of everything in a single statement.

Comment: Thanks the 'for r in' looks good, but I still have the 'select into' issue within the loop then, how would I need to change that?  I will edit the question to show the select.

Comment: No, you don't need any `into` with that syntax. The values will automatically be put into the record variable. See my edit

Comment: I get it that I can access r.something, but how do I use the sum(x) later on?  Is it also available in 'r', but how to assign a name e.g. 'r.quantitysum'?

Comment: OK, I think "select sum(psum.quantity) as purquantitysum" etc seems to work, at least I can create the function, will need to do more work before I can test it all.

Comment: @Werner: correct, you need to give each column a proper (and unique) alias. This is also true if you select two columns with the same name from two tables:  `purchase.id as purchase_id, bot.id as bottle_id` to avoid name clashes

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a cursor. There are several variations on the same theme available. I normally use this:

```
declare mycursor cursor for select a, b from c;
declare d, e bigint;
begin
  loop
    fetch from mycursor into d, e
    exit when not found;
    -- do your thing here
  end loop;
  close mycursor;
  -- maybe do some other stuff
end;
```